# cd and ls wont work in terminal mac.

Tags: macos, terminal

Can anybody explain what is wrong with my terminal:

```
 
$ echo $PATH
=/usr/local/bin
$ ls
-bash: ls: command not found
$ cd
-bash: find: command not found
```

Why won't these commands work? Help? Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your `PATH`.  That `=` character shouldn't be there.  There is no `=/usr/local/bin` directory.  It should be `/usr/local/bin`.  But also, you probably want several other directories on your `PATH`, separated by `:` characters.  Typically, it'll be something like this:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myname/bin
```